# UIWebView appears null when calling fro a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a major problem when trying to access a UIWebView that was created during ViewDidLoad, the UIWebView appears null

here is how i declare the property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *detailsView;
```

the implementation

```
@implementation iPadMainViewController

@synthesize detailsView;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    detailsView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 0, 512, 768)];
    [self.view addSubView:detailsView];
}
```

When accessing from

```
- (void)loadDetailedContent:(NSString *)s
{
    NSLog(@"%@", detailsView);
}
```

I get NULL, is it a normal behavior or am i doing something wrong?

here is the touchesBegan that is being called, from the views subclass that is being touched,

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    iPadMainViewController *mycontroller = [[iPadMainViewController alloc] init];
    self.delegate = mycontroller;

    [self.delegate loadDetailedContent:NewsId];
}
```

Comment: First of all your detailsView (but i would have given the name detailsWebView, any way does not matter) is a properties so you should use **self** operator. and when you are calling your loadDetailedContent method?

Comment: I've change it to self but still it's nil, I'm calling it when a view on the same view controller is touched

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `loadDetailedContent` is not called before `viewDidLoad`? Set breakpoints in both methods and see which one gets hit first.

**EDIT** Since you updated the question with the code, it is easy to see why this problem happens. In `touchesBegan`, you instantiate the `UIViewController` and then call `loadDetailedContent`. This means that `loadDetailedContent` will be called before `viewDidLoad`.

`viewDidLoad` is called first when the view it controls has been created.

Comment: loadDetailedContent is called when a UIView on the same UIViewController is touched, so yes it is called after the viewDidLoad. by the way the UIView that is touched is a subclass that has -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event overridden and which call the loadDetailedContent, may that be the reason?

Comment: Does it call loadDetailedContent on touchesBegan. can you show us the code of touchesBegan? loadDetailedContent is written in the same class file?

Answer (score 0):

1st of all change you synthesize to

```
@synthesize detailsView = _detailsView
```

and allocate your uiwebvie

```
_detailsView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 0, 512, 768)];
```

And try to push your ipadMainController in touchBegan to main screen and in vieDidLoad call loadDetailedContent

Comment: changing to _detailsView did not change anything, I did not get the second point, how do i push the main controller into it's child view??

Comment: If it is your main controller why you're creating delegate to his own :o? Just call [self loadDetailedContent]; And you can have NUll because UIWebView is not a NSString and you're NSLogging %@ which is string, set the breakpoit and chceck webview instance

Comment: no, i have a subclass for the UIView that should accept the touch event, in the subclass i override the "touchesbegan" and call the method of its delegate - the iPadMainView controller, am I doing something stupid? :)